LM317/LM337 configurations for a rail splitter
I am designing a rail splitter to power a high precision board with low current requirements (10-15 mA). Initially I thought about building an opamp-based rail plitter, but then I realized I needed to clean and pre-filter the DC anyhow and opted for Linear Regulators instead.
The main 12V DC power comes from an AC transformer and I clearly see some AC leaking through with the oscilloscope as well as a bit of ripple left.
Right now my question is not about how to filter the ripple or the AC, but rather in which configuration the LM317/LM337 are more stable for the task in hand.
The LM317 is a positive voltage regulator, Vin=12V, Vadj=1.25V,  12V>Vout>0V. The LM337 is a negative voltage regulator, so Vin=-12V, Vadj=-1.25V, 0V>Vout>-12V
By setting LM317 Vout=6 and LM337 Vout=-6, they are effectively pointing to the same voltage, giving us a regulated midpoint (VGND).
I am aware that the LM3x7 can be either regulated with an external voltage in the Vadj pin (in this case, voltage divider between V+ and GND) or with a resistor pair, the first one creating a loop between Vout and Vadj pins and the second resistor between Vadj and GND.
I have found a couple of places where they used the LM317/LM337 to do exactly this using the voltage dividier/external voltage in the Vadj pin here and here but none with the traditional feedback loop of the LM3x7.
I have simulated both circuits with the bare minimum amount of components to make them work (it will be beefed up later with protection mechanisms and noise reduction later), and both seem to behave the same way in simulations.
My question is, which one of these 2 schematics would be more stable or recommended to continue with the design? Why is the voltage divider used more often than the feedback loop described in its normal use in the datasheet?
Feedback loop:

Voltage divider:

Thank you in advance!

Please reveal what currents are flowing through the 1 ohm resistors. Please also reveal what happens to the mid-point voltage when an asymmetrical power load is applied.

When an asymmetrical power load is applied, the mid-point has to stay constant. In the simulation I did try applying different asymmetric loads and I didn't manage to bias the mid-point in either design.
The current flowing through the 1 ohm resistor would be nominally between 10 and 15 mA. I don't expect it to reach the 50mA and I expect it to never exceed the 100mA mark. So for 50 mA it would dissipate about 2.5 mW of heat and a voltage drop of 50 mV. The circuit board which will be powered does not produce spikes in the load, and should be a rather constant current demand.

My concern is that you need more than 10 to 15 mA to keep good mid-point regulation. This means a slightly higher and slightly lower voltage on the output of the two regulators respectively. Because it's a compromise design (should have used a transformer with a centre-tap etc.) you have to demonstrate a lot more about the performance in simulation if you are to expect decent answers (that may have to pick up the baton and do this work for you). If indeed your maximum asymmetrical load currents are 15 mA and 0 mA then you may get away with this.

This is an extension for an existing board that I cannot modify. I have to work with what i've been given. And sadly that is a 12V single rail supply and this board. I need to interface them.
I will finish the design, the only thing I wanted to ask now in here is which of the two voltage regulation strategies would work better, the feedback loop between Vout and Vadj or the voltage divider between Vin and GND. Once I have settled for one of them I will not only simulate it but I have all the components with me to start testing. I just wanted anopinion from someone with more experience.

I am of course open to new designs. I have also taken into consideration rail splitting with opamps, and opamp/transistor AB amplifier designs. But this one attracted me due to simplicity and stability after reading about it.

@andy-aka, I don't expect you to do it for me. I only want to gather opinions and information from people that have more experience than me with LM3x7 and rail splitters to get a good basis for my design. That's all :)

The simplest approach is to use TLE2426 which is designed for this specific application.

@David you said this: I only want to gather opinions and information from people <-- against the rules. The rules do not permit this site to be used for soliciting opinions and your question can be closed. Neither should you wait for opinions before simulating. It takes 30 minutes to simulate both circuits and start getting results. Anyone wanting to answer this question (as it stands) would have to make a simulation so, it brings me back to what I said earlier. This is a question and answer site and, not a forum.

@Andyaka, I think we are having a misunderstanding, let me rephrase it. I did simulate both circuits. The screenshots attached are the actual simulations I am running. I have not found any information about pros and cons between both schematics and why one is used and the other is not. So I came here to ask to people with more experience/expertise with the LM3x7 about it. I did read all the rules and I didn't think that was against them. If it is, please forgive me, and I'll edit/remove/close the the question.

@user131342 I also thought about that and you're totally right. I was worried though that with Io_max=47mA at some point I could overload the rails. Maybe oversizing it more as I was trying to do is counterproductive.

You haven't performed any transient condition simulations as far as I can tell. Steady-state analysis simulations under no-load conditions (as per what you have posted) are virtually worthless in this respect. So no, in my book, you have not performed any valid simulations that are meaningful.

Your designs have \$R_5+R_6=2\Omega\$ between two regulator outputs. This will produce \$\frac{\Delta V}{2\Omega}\$ of quiescent current (wasted power), which is 0.5A per volt of difference between those outputs.
Your use of LM317/LM337 implies that you expect hundreds of milliamps of current in/out of this manufactured GND. However, R5 and R6 produce a combined impedance of \$1\Omega \parallel 1\Omega = 0.5\Omega\$ of source impedance, which is going to develop hundreds of millivolts under those conditions. That's not a big problem if every sub-system of your system is ground-referenced, but you will be severely testing the PSRR of those elements. To each amplifier, it will appear as if the +6V and −6V rails have hundreds of millivolts of ripple.
I think this design is only good for tens of millivolts of ground current, at best, making the LM317 and LM337 a bit redundant.
The regulators will not regulate well if ground current has frequency components in the kilohertz. It's not clear to me how big a problem this is, but I suspect that source impedance of your fake 0V might be intolerably high at frequency.
I think you're better of with the op-amp + class AB stage, which will have lower impedance at frequency (better bandwidth), no dependence upon an exact supply voltage, higher current ability, lower quiescent current, and will stay much closer to the midpoint of the 12V supply.
Also, consider the BUF634.

That's a fair point, I might think about changing it, thx! I could also lower r5 and r6. The problem here is not the board which is powered. That board has tonnes of noise attenuation circuitry and when powered with a clean DC source (+-6v out of batteries) the output signal is immaculate. The problem here is cleaning the 12V single supply rail (which I can't change) and splitting it. That Single board is the only subsystem using the virtual rail because it contains a couple of precision opamp circuitry. After the board, the signal goes back to its original single rail with an offset of +6v.

What I am really interested in knowing is, taking into account it's limitations and flaws, would both of the schematics of my post work or not. Why no one seems to use the feedback loop strategy as shown in the datasheets and instead go for a voltage divider between vcc and gnd?

Thank you for pointing to the BUF634. So far for the op-amp based simulations I had been using the LM759, which is the one I have laying around. I think I will revisit the op-amp strategy using the negative feedback loop with some capacitors to get rid of the parasitic AC component in the DC supply, as it seems it might work better overall (although this gets out of the scope fo my original question and won't know until I finish simulate them) :)

@David I've been staring at those two schematics of yours for ages, and I can't see any feedback. Those regulators produce fixed potentials which aren't at all adjusted as a function of the GND potential (wrt. the source supply). I don't think there's any functional difference between them.
